# lua command won't work in lua.exe

Tags: command-line, lua

I'm just starting out trying to learn lua, an I'm running into a problem getting it to run my programs. I saved the program as a .lua, and tried:

lua filename.lua

but I get the following error

stdin:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (global 'lua')
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?

I followed the installation instructions here in the readme file included in the lua-5.3.5 folder that I downloaded from lua.org

I can get the lua.exe console to run commands that I type directly into it, but I haven't been able to get it to run pre-written stuff.

Thank you

The file is a hello world program:

print("Hello World")

Comment: It might help if you told us what’s in the file.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Yup, that sounds like a syntax erroe, so we can't help you without knowing what you've written.